# What is せる followed by suru-verbs?

Tags: verbs, classical-japanese

> 専売特許に違背**せる**物品　infringements on patents
>
> 和英字書を編集**せる**はヘボン博士をもって嚆矢とす。Dr. Hepburn was the first to compile a Japanese-English dictionary.

Is it する・す mizenkei followed by り rentaikei ([here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/230313/m1u/%E3%82%8A/)), or something else?

Comment: Where did you get these sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're the 未然形 of す, followed by the 連体形 of the so-called [完了の「り」](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009007.htm) in 文語. (It has nothing to do with the causative auxiliary verb せる used today.)

In modern Japanese 口語,

- 専売特許に違背せる物品 ≒ 専売特許に違反した物品
- 和英字書を編集せるは… ≒ 和英辞書を編集した**の**は…

Also see [this chiebukuro Q&A](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1411392644).

Comment: Is this usage still contemporary in academic writing or no? I saw lots of this while I was reading 西田幾多郎全集.

Comment: @virmaior No, 文語 is not actively used after WWII.